# Xvfb top-left adjustment

Tags: x11, xorg, xvfb

I have an X11 virtual frame buffer that I would like to run just one particular program in so that I can connect and disconnect from either my desktop or tablet without closing the program (and also without running a full desktop manager). Everything works great except the window top left of the window is off by a few hundred pixels each, is it possible to adjust this on an xvfb?

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the default location for opening windows in an Xvfb environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848225/setting-the-default-location-for-opening-windows-in-an-xvfb-environment)

Comment: @velop not a duplicate, notice in the other question the comment about running TWM? the issue here was not running a window manager. Once a window manager was used the issue was resolved (hence my answer).

Comment: Oh I thought that Xvfb is already an simple window manager. But actually the questioner Gustaf does not say that he is using twm. Anyway which window manager did you use in the end?

Comment: I believe it was TWM I ended up with. Whichever lightweight tiling manager will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your application with the option ‘-geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT+0+0‘ replacing WIDTH and HEIGHT with the screen size.  See ‘man X‘ for a description of the -geometry option.

Comment: this produced didn't work, perhaps wine doesn't have these settings

Comment: Bummer. I guess wine is different.  My only other suggestion is to try running wine's `regedit` command to see if the initial window location is specified in the registry, either under *Software->Wine->AppDefaults->your-app* or possibly under *Software->Wine->X11 Driver->Desktop*

Comment: Isn't it double dashes? `--geometry`?

Answer (score 0):

seems the issue was with not running a window manager, I thought you could get away with it, guess not!